# Idiomatic Way to Set & Update Clojure Namespace Flags?

Tags: clojure, ring

I have a ring/compojure based web API and I need to be able to optionally turn on and off caching (or any flag for that matter) depending on a startup flag or having a param passed in to the request.

I tried having the flag set as a dynamic var:

```
(def ^:dynamic *cache* true)

(defmacro cache [source record options & body]
  `(let [cachekey# (gen-cachekey ~source ~record ~options)]
     (if-let [cacheval# (if (and (:ttl ~source) ~*cache*) (mc/generic-get cachekey#) nil)]
       cacheval#
       (let [ret# (do ~@body)]
         (if (and (:ttl ~source) ~*cache*) (mc/generic-set cachekey# ret# :ttl (:ttl ~source)))
         ret#))))
```

...but that only allows me to update the flag within a binding block which isn't ideal to wrap every data fetching function, and it din't allow me to optionally set the flag on start up

I then tried to set the flag in an atom, which allowed me to set the flag on the start up, and easily update the flag if a certain param was passed to the request, but the update would be changing the flag for all threads and not just the specific request's flag.

What's the most idiomatic way to do something like this in Clojure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, unquoting `*cache*` in your macro definition means that it's compile-time value will be included in the compiled output and rebinding it at runtime will have no effect. If you want the value to be looked up at runtime, you should not unquote `*cache*`.

As for the actual question: if you want the various data fetching functions to react to a cache setting, you'll need to communicate it to them somehow anyway. Additionally, there are the two separate concerns of (1) computing the relevant flag values, (2) making them available to the handler so that it can communicate them to the functions which care.

### Computing flag values and making them available to the main handler

For decisions on a per-request basis, examining some incoming parameters and settings, you might want to use a piece of middleware which will determine the correct values of the various flags and `assoc` them onto the request map. This way handlers living downstream from this piece of middleware will be able to look them up in the request map without knowing how they were computed.

You can of course install multiple pieces of middleware, each responsible for computing a different set of flags.

If you do use middleware, you'll likely want it to handle the default values. In this case, the note about setting defaults at startup in the section on dynamic Vars below may not be relevant.

Finally, if the application-level (global, thread-independent) defaults might change at runtime (as a result of a "turn off all caching" request, perhaps), you can store these in Atoms.

### Communicating flag values to functions which care

#### First approach: dynamic Vars

Once you do that, you'll have to communicate the flags to the functions which actually perform operations where the flags are relevant; here dynamic Vars and explicit arguments are the most natural options.

Using a dynamic Var means that you don't have to do it explicitly for every function call involving such functions; instead, you can do it once per request, say. Installing a default value at startup is quite possible too; for example, you could use `alter-var-root` for that. (Or you could simply define the initial value of the Var in terms of information obtained from the environment.)

NB. if you launch new threads within the scope of a `binding` block, they will not see the bindings installed by this `binding` block automatically -- you'll have to arrange for them to be transmitted. The `bound-fn` macro is useful for creating functions which handle this automatically; see `(doc bound-fn)` for details.

The idea of using a single map with all flags described below is relevant here too, if perhaps not equally necessary for reasonable convenience; in essence, you'd be using a single dynamic Var instead of many.

#### Second approach: explicit arguments and flag maps

The other natural option is simply to pass in any relevant flags to the functions which need them. If you pass all the flags in a map, you can just assemble all options relevant to a request in a single map and pass it in to all the flag-aware functions without caring which flags any given function needs (as each function will simply examine the map for the flags it cares about, disregarding the others).

With this approach, you'll likely want to split the data fetching functionality into a function to get the value from the cache, a function to get the value from the data store and a flag-aware function which calls one of the other two depending on the flag value. This way you can, for example, test them separately. (Although if the individual functions really are completely trivial, I'd say it's ok to create only the flag-taking version at first; just remember to factor out any pieces which become more complex in the course of development.)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Good catch on the macro, and yes, I am/will be using ring middleware to capture any request param (middleware is awesome). My goal was to find a way to get the functionality I need without having to pass a cache boolean, inclosed in a map or not, from the route, to the interface, to the db layer, etc... It sounds like maybe alter-var-root might be my best bet.